# How to have a single regular expression that contains two regexs separated by an "or" condition so that my text validates to these two only?

Tags: regex

I want to use two regular expressions for my textbox and out of the two I want only one to be used at a time based on some condition?

Is there any way I can form a single regular expression which contains an "or" in it without requiring me to explicitly set an "or" in my code?

The two expressions are:

```
^[0-9]+$
```

i.e. use only digits

```
^[A-Za-z]{6}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{3}[A-Za-z]{1}$
```

i.e. use the format `ABCDEF23G45D786Z`.

Thanks

Comment: Alternation constructs; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36xybswe

Comment: What do you mean by, "…based on some condition?"

Comment: Why is this tagged both as c# and javascript?

Comment: Try `^(\d+)|([A-Za-z]{6}[\dLMNPQRSTUV]{2}[A-Za-z][\dLMNPQRSTUV]{2}[A-Za-z][\dLMNPQRSTUV]{3}[A-Za-z])$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `|` character signifies an OR.

```
((first regex statement)|(second regex statement))
```